# XSLT combine "params" with "match="@*|node()"

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

**GOAL**

Output an XML with the exact input names and variables as the XML my XSLT receive + 2 params from external sources

**PSEUDOCODE** - XSLT(1.0) I'm using variables instead of params so it's easier to test

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="StatusCode" select="'11111111111'">
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="StatusMessage" select="'########'">
    </xsl:variable>

<!-- BLOCK 1 -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
<!-- ------- -->

<!-- BLOCK 2 -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <StatusCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="$StatusCode"/>
        </StatusCode>
        <StatusMessage>
            <xsl:value-of select="$StatusMessage"/>
        </StatusMessage>
    </xsl:template> 
<!-- ------- -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PROBLEM**

If I try "BLOCK 1" or "BLOCK 2" independently, they work, but I couldn't as desired combine them both

Comment: Please show an example input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `BLOCK 2` template is applied first, because it matches the root node. This template contains no `xsl:apply-templates` instructions - so the other template is never executed.

The question is WHERE do you want the added nodes to appear. You could do:

```
<!-- BLOCK 2 -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <StatusCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="$StatusCode"/>
        </StatusCode>
        <StatusMessage>
            <xsl:value-of select="$StatusMessage"/>
        </StatusMessage>
    </xsl:template> 
<!-- ------- -->
```

but this would place the added nodes outside the root element, making the result an XML fragment instead of well-formed XML document.

Comment: the desired node structure is exactly your example. Problem solved :)